# Generate Document id in Elasticsearch based on document

Tags: elasticsearch, hash

Is there any support provided by Elasticsearch to generate hash id based on document content?

If not, which hashing algorithm should I use for better distribution across shards and efficiency with rare collisions, if I can expect around a couple of million events per day being indexed to my Elasticsearch cluster?

With my research, I have found 3 candidates for my problem: `murmur3`, `md5`, `sha256` (128 would suffice?).

Comment: You should take a look at this blog article (if not already done) : https://www.elastic.co/blog/efficient-duplicate-prevention-for-event-based-data-in-elasticsearch

Comment: Have gone through this, but why it doesn't suggest murmur3 which is one of the fastest and is rare collision algorithm according to this study https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/145633. Even ES uses mumur3 to generate doc id